# Keeping a footer below an object

Tags: html, css

I inserted my resume as part of an object in html for my website. I have tried everything from setting my footer to absolute, floating my object to the left, putting my object in a div, inserting hr to break the header/footer space.

Here is a link to the page. I think you will see the problem right away. I am completely self taught so that could be part of the problem....
http://buildingautomationmonthly.com/resume.html

Here is Resume.HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
  <title>Building Automation Monthly: Resume</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <!-- modernizr enables HTML5 elements and feature detects -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

    <header>
      <div id="strapline">
        <div id="welcome_slogan">
          <h3>Building Automation Monthly</h3>
        </div><!--close welcome_slogan-->
      </div><!--close strapline-->    
      <nav>
        <div id="menubar">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="About Phil.html">About Phil</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.blog.buildingautomationmonthly.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--close menubar-->  
      </nav>
    </header>
    <hr>




      <div id="content">
        <div class="content_item">
          <h2>Phil Zito</h2>
          <object width="800" height="800" data="Phil Zito-Resume.pdf"></object>



    </div><!--close site content-->       

  </div><!--close main-->

  </hr>
  <footer style="float:center">

    <div id="footer_content">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="About Phil.html">About Phil</a> | <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a> | <a href="projects.html">Projects</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br/><br/>
        <p> Developed and Coded by Phil Zito </p>
    </div><!--close footer_content--> 
  </footer>    

  <!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_slide.js"></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Here is Style.css

```
    @font-face { 
  font-family: News Cycle; 
    src: url('../fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.eot'); 
    src: local("News Cycle"), url('../fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.ttf'); 
} 

html
{ height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: normal 90% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background: #000;
}

/* tell the browser to render HTML 5 elements as block */
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { 
  display:block;
}

p
{ padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 100% }

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% 'News Cycle', Arial,  sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 165% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;}

h3
{ font: normal 160% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
  font: normal 150% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.5em;}

h5, h6
{ font: normal 95% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  padding-bottom: 15px;}

span
{ color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;}

a, a:hover
{ color: #000;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;}

a:hover
{ text-decoration: none;}

ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 30px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 100%;}

ol
{ margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;}

ol li
{ margin: 0 0 11px 0;}

#main, header, #banner, #menubar, #site_content, footer, #content_grey, nav, #slideshow_container, #footer_content
{ margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;}

#main
{ background: #fff;}

header
{ height: 150px;
  background: #CCC;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#BBB, #FFF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#BBB, #FFF);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#BBB, #FFF);}

nav
{ height: 60px;
  background: transparent;}  

#strapline
{ width: 940px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0 auto;} 

#welcome_slogan
{ width: 940px;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;  
  margin: 0 auto;}    

#welcome_slogan h3
{ font: bold 300% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  color: #000;} 

#menubar
{ width: 940px;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;}    

ul#nav
{ margin:0;}

ul#nav li
{ padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  display: inline;
  background: transparent;}

ul#nav li a
{ float: left;
  font: bold 130% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 8px 20px 0 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
  padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  color: #000;  } 

ul#nav li.current a, ul#nav li:hover a
{ text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
  color: #000;
  background: #E8D82A;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;  }

#slideshow_container
{ height: 270px;
  padding-top: 20px;}

.slideshow
{ width: 940px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;}  

/* styling for the slideshow on the homepage */
ul.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  width: 940px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;}

ul.slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;}

ul.slideshow li.show {
  z-index: 500;}

ul img {
  border: none;}

#slideshow-caption {
  width: 940px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 500;}

#slideshow-caption .slideshow-caption-container {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; 
  background: transparent url(../images/transparent.png) repeat;  
  z-index: 1000;}

#slideshow-caption p {
  padding: 0;
  font: normal 130% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;}  

#site_content
{ width: 940px;
  overflow: hidden;} 

.sidebar_container
{ float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10;
  width: 240px;}

.sidebar
{ float: left;
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;}

.sidebar_item
{ font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 240px;}

.sidebar h2
{ padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  font: normal 140% 'News Cycle', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 30px;}  

#content
{ width: 680px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  float: right;}

.content_item
{ width: 660px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;}

.content_container
{ width: 320px;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
  float: left;}

footer
{ background: #CCC;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
  margin-bottom: -20px;}

#footer_content{
  width: 940px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;  
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  color: #000;}

footer a, footer a:hover
{ text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;}

footer a:hover
{ text-decoration: underline;}

 .button_small
{ font: normal 110% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px 7px 10px;
  background: #E8D82A;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;}

.button_small a
{ color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;}

.form_settings
{ margin: 15px 0 0 0;}

.form_settings p
{ padding: 0 0 4px 0;}

.form_settings span
{ float: left; 
  width: 280px; 
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #000;}

.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea
{ padding: 2px; 
  width: 299px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;}

.form_settings input[type="checkbox"]
{ padding: 2px 0; 
  width: 15px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 0; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;
  margin: 28px 0;}

.form_settings .submit
{ font: bold 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid; 
  width: 99px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 206px; 
  height: 26px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #E8D82A;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F2E986, #CFC017);
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;}

 .email
{ padding: 0 0 10px -200px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 100% }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float:center` from your footer inline style to make your `footer` a footer and the following style.

Reason is that your content's `float` is carried to the footer and you can reset the floats by just mentioning `clear:both`.

Add this to your footer

```
footer {
background: #CCC;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #BBB);
margin-bottom: -20px;
clear: both; // add this
}
```

See if this is what you are looking for.

Apart form this you have a `float:right` on your content. probably you man want to float it left.

Just as a pointer; this [may be](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) a good read.